# How can I improve run time in loops?

Tags: loops

I am comparing two cells on different sheets (Text1, Text2).  If there is a match then I copy the first 3 columns from Text1 to Text2 sheet.  I may have as many as 1000 rows.  The current code I am using times out.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(text1))
var lastrowold = ss.getSheetByName(text1).getLastRow() + 2
var lastrownew = ss.getSheetByName(text2).getLastRow() + 2

for (var old=2; old<lastrownew; old++){
  var nv =  ss.getSheetByName(text2).getRange(old,4).getValue()         
  for (var n=2; n<lastrowold; n++){
    if(nv == ss.getSheetByName(text1).getRange(n,4).getValue()){
      ss.getSheetByName(text1).getRange(n,1,1,3).copyTo(ss.getSheetByName(text2).getRange(old,1,1,3))
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What language is this supposed to be?

Comment: Google Sheets Script

Answer (score 0):

Stop unnecessarily repeating work.  For example,

```
ss.getSheetByName(text2).getRange(old,4).getValue()
```

only needs to be re-computed when `old` changes, so it can be done before the inner loop starts and saved in a variable that get used in that inner loop.

Comment: I will try that.  Also, is there a way to get out of the inner loop once a match is found?

Comment: Consult your Google Sheets Script documentation for how to break out of a loop.

Comment: I think I made the modifications you suggested but its still only getting about 1/2 through the task. Its processing about 360 lines out of 600.  See above code (edited)

Comment: There is another expression using `old` which can be *hoisted*.  You might also save values you visit in `text1` in an array.